# What is service id in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I recently got an email with the subject Your Service ID password will expire within 60 days -- ###.####.## Network(Active Directory))
Is this service Id related to my organization? Sorry, I am newbie to azure so do not know what exactly is this.

Answer (score 0):

Service IDs generally contain client credentials like Client ID and Client Secret and are used for authenticating users. In some Azure-connected services this field is used to replace username/password authentication. Are you using any connected services or was the email from Azure itself? I have not yet seen this field in Azure.

https://www.blueworkslive.com/scr/docs/bwl/topics/service_ids.html